# Regarding Scrapy, I am having trouble navigating pages using the linkextraction rules, and I think it has something to do with the allow parameter

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Sorry, I am quite new to Scrapy, and having trouble finding resources for recursive scraping and rule-defining. I simply want to scrape all the job listings in the start-url as well as the follow the next page link until there's no more. I am able to follow a tutorial and scrape one page successfully. However, implementing the `CrawlSpider` to go further than a page has been tricky.

Code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/jjj?query=West+LA"]

    rules = (Rule (LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=('s=d00',),restrict_xpaths=('//p[@class="button next"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = TutorialItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

The html portion where I think I'm having trouble is:

```
<a class="button next" title="next page" href="/search/jjj?s=100&query=west%20LA&sort=date">
```

When you go to each page, the only part that changes is the s=d00 part. Is defining that in the allow parameter my problem?

Also, if anyone can recommend more introductory tutorials for recursive scraping, that would be beneficial as well. I've exhausted: http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/#.VRBK_ZN4r-a

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match one or more digits as a value of `s`:

```
allow=r"s=\d+"
```

Besides, your `restict_xpaths` setting is pointing to a `p` element with `class="button next"` while there is only `a` element with this class value. In other words, replace:

```
restrict_xpaths=('//p[@class="button next"]',)
```

with:

```
restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="button next"]'
```

Note that it can be set as string also (no need for a tuple).

Comment: Thanks. In leyman's term, how is the allow parameter usually customized?

Comment: @PeterLi it is a regular expression or several regular expressions that are used to distinguish the desired links from others, `href` attribute is checked ([docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor)). Hope that helps.